# Which ports will python use to send html request? with urllib or urllib2

Tags: python, http, port, urllib

I'm using webpy to make a small site. When I want to use OAuth, i find that the firewall will stop the http request to any site, I even can't use IE to browse the Internet.

So i asked the aministrator to open some ports for me, but i don't know which ports will be used by python or IE to send http request.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I assume you're talking about the remote ports. In that case, just tell the admin to open the standard web ports. Really, if your admin doesn't know how to make IE work through the firewall, he's hopeless. I suggest walking up to random people on the street and say "80 and 443" until someone looks up, then fire your admin and hire that guy; he can't be any worse.

If your admin *does* know what he's doing, and wants you to use an HTTP proxy instead of connecting directly, ask him to set up the proxy for you in IE, look at the settings he uses, then come back here and search for how to use HTTP proxies in Python (there are lots of answers on that), and ask for help if you get stuck.

If you're talking about the local ports, because you're got an insane firewall, they'll be picked at random from some large range. If you want to cover every common OS, you need all of 1024-65535 to be opened up, although if you only need to deal with a single platform, most use a smaller range than that, and if the machine won't be doing much but running your program, most have a way to restrict it to an even smaller range (e.g., as small as 255 ports on Windows). Google "ephemeral port" for details.

If you need to restrict your local port, the key is to call [`bind`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.bind) on your socket before calling `connect`. If you think you're talking about the local ports, you're probably wrong. Go ask your admin (or the new one you just hired) and make sure. But if you are…

If you're using `urllib`/`urllib2`, it does not have any way to do what you want, so you can't do that anymore. You can drop down to [`httplib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html#httplib.HTTPConnection), which lets you pass a `source_address`, a `(host, port)` tuple that it will use to bind the socket before connecting. It's not as simple as what you're using, but it's a lot easier than implementing HTTP from scratch.

You might also want to look at [requests](http://python-requests.org), which I know has its own [native OAuth](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#oauth-authentication) support, and probably has a way to specify a source address. (I haven't looked, but I usually find that whenever I want to know if `requests` can do X, it can, and in the most obvious way I think of…) The API for `requests` is generally similar to `urllib2` when `urllib2` is sane, simpler and cleaner when `urllib2` is messy, so it's usually pretty easy to port things.

At any rate, however you do this, you will have to consider the fact that only one socket can be bound to the same local port at a time. So, what happens if two programs are running at once, and they both need to make an outbound connections, and your admin has only given you one port? One of them will fail. Is that acceptable?

If not, what you really need to do is open a range of ports, and write code that does a `random.shuffle` on the range, then tries to `bind` them until one succeeds. Which means you'll need an HTTP library that lets you feed in a socket factory or a pre-opened socket instead of just specifying a port, which most of them do not, which probably means you'll be hacking up a copy of the `httplib` source.

If all else fails, you can always set up a local proxy that binds to whatever source port (or port range) you want when proxying outward. Then you can just use your favorite high-level library, as-is, and connect to the local proxy, and there's no way the firewall can tell what's going on behind the proxy.

As you can see, this is not easy. That's mainly because you very actually rarely this.

Comment: i'm talking about the local ports, so can i make it a certain one?

Comment: @MangMang: Are you _sure_ you're talking about the local ports? If so, it's going to be tricky. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: @abarnert yes... so, i can ask the administrator to allow outgoing connections from port 1024-49151?

Comment: @MangMang: Yes, if local ports are the issue, and you can get him to allow outgoing connections from ports 1024-49151 to ports 80 and 443, you're set. But anyone who's restricted outgoing connections on all local ports is unlikely to open up all of them for you.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Maybe it's just because I live in San Francisco, but it seems to work for me. :)

Comment: @abarnert thank u, and i find this page in microsoft's website(http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929851), since the server's system is windows server 2008. so i can ask the admin to allow outgoing connections from 49152 to 65535.

Comment: @abarnert As you can see in the title, i am using urllib

Comment: @MangMang: I didn't realize they'd changed that. It used to be that 1024-49151 was enough to handle every common OS's ephemeral/dynamic port mapping, but I guess now it has to be 1024-65535… I'll keep that in mind for the future; thanks for pointing it out. However, that page does show another option. If the machine is going to be doing nothing else at all, you can set the dynamic port range system-wide to something pretty narrow and specific, like, say, 32768-33023, and then ask your admin to open just that range for you.

Answer (score 5):

Generally when a program wants to use a port but doesn't care which number it has, it uses an "[ephemeral port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ephemeral_port)."  This is typical for client applications, where the remote port is fixed (by the server), but the local port doesn't make any difference.

Often a firewall will allow outgoing connections from any port, simply blocking incoming connections to unknown ports, on the theory that internal machines making outgoing requests should be allowed to decide what is proper, and that bad actors are all on the "public" side.

You may find that your administrator requires you to use an "HTTP proxy."  If so, here are the instructions for Ruby which I imagine you can port to Python: [Ruby and Rails - oauth and http proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1153488/ruby-and-rails-oauth-and-http-proxy)